# SortedSet in order?

Tags: c#, .net, set

As mentioned in [SortedSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a collection of objects that is maintained in sorted order

how is "in order" defined in a `SortedSet`?

In order which they were added. Is it customizable so it can be sorted by alphabet?

Comment: Construct it with an IComparer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395024(v=vs.110).aspx ) and pass in the appropriate StringComparer ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx ).

Comment: You even linked to the page that answers your question (the documentation for that type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it uses a comparer, it doesn't remember the order in which the elements were added.

There's a constructor overload which takes a `IComparer<T>` parameter. The default constructor uses `Comparer<T>.Default`.

For instance, here's a sorted set of strings which ignores case:

```
var ignoreCaseSet = new SortedSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski If I have  `new SortedSet<Room>()` and the Room has a `RoomId` property. what Comparer is there to sort this by `RoomId`?

Comment: You can implement `IComparer<Room>` yourself.

Comment: @RayOldProf One simple way:`Comparer<Room>.Create((a, b) => a.RoomId.CompareTo(b.RoomId))`